# Conan for consuming a dependency seems to not work in conanfile.txt

Tags: conan

Firstly I know this question is been asked for a while among various channels but since I am very new to conan there are things I still don't understand even after reading other answers and posts.
We have a task in our project where we need to use a third party library gdal to be installed. Hence my conanfile.txt looked like this:

```
[requires]
libexif/0.6.23
sdl/2.0.20
nlohmann_json/3.10.5 
yaml-cpp/0.6.3
gdal/3.4.3
openssl/1.1.1o
libjpeg-turbo/2.0.5

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

Now after running conan install I encountered following issue :

```
*ERROR: At least two recipes provides the same functionality:
 - 'libjpeg' provided by 'libjpeg-turbo/2.0.5', 'libjpeg/9d'
```

After searching online for results, it leads to this page https://docs.conan.io/en/1.46/reference/conanfile/attributes.html
where they said to use "Provides" in order to distinguish recipes providing same functionality. But what i don't understand is that I am not using a conanfile.py (which is a recipe). The conanfile.txt is similar to requirements file and unfortunately we don't want to make it complex as none in our team are familiar with conan so we are trying to find a way to fix it in conanfile.txt.
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The conflict in dependencies will come exactly the same using a ``conanfile.txt`` and a ``conanfile.py``. The issue is not how you are consuming them, but that there are incompatibilities. You might need to remove ``libjpeg-turbo``, or try to check if the other libraries you are using have an option like ``use_libjpeg_turbo`` or the like, that you can configure for this (I can see for example ``freeimage`` has ``"with_jpeg": [False, "libjpeg", "libjpeg-turbo"],``). Use ``conan info`` to get details for your dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think  we cant remove the libjpeg-turbo library as it seems to be used somewhere in the code(not sure where), I also checked the libraries using libjpeg-turbo, and tried to set it true in options section of conanfile, but ends up having same error of incompatibilities. Is there a way where I can use both libjpeg-turbo and libjpeg.

Comment: That is the thing, libjpeg and libjpeg-turbo are almost drop-in replacements (libjpeg-turbo implements the libjpeg API + more), same interfaces, same symbols, etc. So trying to link the two of them in the same application will give link errors, this is not related to the package manager, you really need to use exclusively one of them. If you can only use ``libjpeg-turbo``, then you need to keep pushing it into the dependencies. If some doesn't implement the option, you might need to fork it, and change the requires yourself, and ``conan create``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With following command you can check what requires the libjpeg: `conan info gdal/3.4.3@`

From the output you can see that gdal and libtiff (libtiff is required by gdal) both require libjpeg:

```
libjpeg/9d
...
    Required by:
        gdal/3.4.3
        libtiff/4.3.0
```

So you need to use the options to switch jpeg implementation for both libtiff and gdal as follows:

```
[requires]
...

[generators]
...

[options]
gdal:with_jpeg=libjpeg-turbo
libtiff:jpeg=libjpeg-turbo
```

Answer (score 0):

gdal has options

```
options = {
...
"with_pcidsk": [True, False],

"with_jpeg": [None, "libjpeg", "libjpeg-turbo"],

"with_charls": [True, False],
...
```

so just modify your conanfile.txt with [options] block:

```
[requires]
...

[generators]
...

[options]
gdal:with_jpeg=libjpeg-turbo
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer grinchenko, But even after providing the options, it seems to not work. Now if I put gdal:with_jpeg=libjpeg-turbo in options, then the gdal itself is not seems to install from conan centre, So this actually not solving the issue :(

Comment: Maybe you should install with following command : conan install <path to conanfile> --build missing